# Is there any way of decoding all of that ViewState garbage that ASP.NET applications pass to the front end?

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

For instance I was looking at the request from a asp.net application and it passes a view state form variable when the form is submitted that looks like this:

```
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUJMzc4ODIxMTU4D2QWAgIBD2QWCgICDxYCHgRUZXh0BQVlbi1VU2QCBA9kFgICAQ8WAh4JaW5uZXJodG1sBTlDV0RTIC0gQ2VydGlmaWVkIFRBQS9XSUEgVHJhaW5pbmcgUHJvZ3JhbXMvUHJvdmlkZXJzIExpc3RkAg4PFgIeBXN0eWxlBSRWSVNJQklMSVRZOmhpZGRlbjtwb3NpdGlvbjphYnNvbHV0ZTtkAhAPDxYCHgtOYXZpZ2F0ZVVybGVkZAISD2QWDAIBD2QWAgIBD2QWIAIBDw8WAh8DBSh
```

Comment: If it's garbage, why do you want to decode it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several viewstate decoders out there.  For example: http://sourceforge.net/projects/viewstate/